# Change shape of FullCalendar event

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

Is it possible to change shape and sorting type of FullCalendar events?

I want to show events like in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better to stick to the layout options FullCalendar provides. You can also code a view from scratch:
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/